# Very, very corrupt SD card, very hard to reformat, using every tool I can think of

Tags: partitioning, gparted, sd-card

Sigh. This is a tough one. I'm exhausted from trying to wrestle with a piece of technology that ought to be a bit more user friendly, so I'll just give a rough overview of what my impression of what has happened is:

- Unplugged SD card at wrong time
- Tried fsck and e2fsck: Doesn't work (fixes some errors but notification that errors remain)
- File browser no longer detects SD card but it does appear in /dev/
- Used GParted to reformat as FAT32 (what I need for my Raspberry Pi--but possibly compatibility issues as a 128GB I am under the impression may need an exFAT format? I'm not sure on this one)
- Tons of errors from GParted! Resulting partition after operation is "Unknown"
- However, was able to remove previous corrupt partitions successfully (with errors)
- Will now try simply erasing all partitions on the card again (should work, as it worked last time) and...
- Retrying the format
- Got a message from GParted that it was a good idea to reboot my entire laptop for some reason? Just to detect the SD card or some such? Not sure. Haven't done that yet. Will erase the whole card and then reboot I suppose.
- Haven't tried Raspberry Pi's format tool yet; good backup option fit-for-purpose in case Ubuntu format/repair tools do not work
- Obviously using the GUI/Nautilus/File Browser to do a simple format (right click > format) doesn't seem to work, whether the card is detected or not
- Occasional I/O errors (does my laptop's card reader even work? Is there a way to check this?)

That's about it. So, I'll try to update as I go along how wrestling with this card goes.

Many thanks.

Comment: plug in another sd card, if it works, throw away this one. this happens all the time

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, I was in effect trying to resurrect a dead SD. I will discontinue this effort and just buy a new one. Best.